# how to create and update the date in d.M.Y format in to database in yii2 basic?

Tags: php, date, yii2-basic-app

In my code I have 3 dates (Joining date, Confirmation dates & Relieving date) for the employee in d.M.Y format, when I create and update theses dates in the database always getting default dates only.
Pls any one help me.

Comment: can you please show your try? what is exact format? and wht format you wants ? paste your code here

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller inside Create Action Try this .

```
$model->created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

In your Controller inside update Action Try this .

```
$model->updated_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: In my controller i am having like this $model->Joining_date=date('d-M-Y');
It save as default date only.

Comment: @Ammu : Check the structure of your table in db.
Your datatype should be datetime for Joining_date. 
Select none from default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$model->Joining_date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['YourModelname']['Joining_date']));
```

Or Else

Check the structure of your table in db. Your datatype should be datetime for Joining_date. Select none from default.

Comment: In my database ,i have datatype date for Joining_date because i need date only and (d-M-Y)format.

Comment: @Ammu Try to achieve your goal by using Kartik Widget.

http://webtips.krajee.com/save-display-date-time-fields-different-formats-yii2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all i got it

In model, add like this

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $this->date1 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date1, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $this->date2 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date2, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    $this->date3 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date3, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    parent::beforeSave($insert);
    return true;
}

public function afterFind()
{
    $this->date1 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date1, 'd-M-Y');
    $this->date2 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date2, 'd-M-Y');
    $this->date3 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->date3, 'd-M-Y');
    parent::afterFind();
    return true;
}
```